How do you measure exactly 31 minutes by burning the ropes?
Beginner puzzle (suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving)

You have two ropes and several matches.
One rope takes 24 minutes to burn completely when lit from either end but it does not burn uniformly.
The other rope takes 50 minutes to burn completely when lit from either end but it does not burn uniformly.
You can’t assume that the burn rates of the two ropes are in any way related other than the total burn times given above.
You can assume that you can light different parts of the same or different ropes simultaneously.
How do you measure exactly 31 minutes by burning the ropes?

Attribution:  MIT Technology Review July August 2000

Strongly related: how many time intervals can be measured with 2 ropes each taking 1 hour to burn and how many time intervals can be measured with N ropes each taking 1 hour to burn.

There's potentially another answer if we're allowed to burn both sides, but then we pull the middle to another side and light it up too. It would make the rope burn up in 1/4 of the normal time it would have.

@Nautilus That assumes that the middle of the rope is the middle of the burn time, which is forbidden in the problem's construction. If one side burns out faster than the other, you cannot use the fast time or the slow time.

@Nautilus The rope does not burn uniformly. Lighting the rope at both ends and the midpoint will almost surely cause the two halves to burn for different durations, neither of which is equal to 1/4 the total duration.

I would

 First light the 2 ends of the 24 minutes rope and 1 end of the 50 minutes one at the same time.
 When the first rope is entirely burned 12 minutes (24/2) will have passed. I then light the other end of the second rope.
 The remaining time of it burning will be (50-12)/2 = 19 minutes for a total time of 12 + 19 = 31 minutes.


Uh-huh, you beat me to it.

I don't think this can be right. "When the first rope is entirely burned 12 minutes (24/2) will have passed." This can't be right, because the ropes burn not uniformly!

Lighting it from both ends simultaneously must cause it to burn up in 12 minutes, otherwise it is unable to burn out in 24. It would either have to go faster on both sides or slower on both sides than 12 minutes each, but that requires more or less total time than it must use. @AldusBumblebore

Exactly, we only care about time here and not length of rope burned. If you lit just the left end of the rope and extinguished it after 12 minutes then you'd know there must be 12 minutes of rope remaining on the right side to hit the 24 minute total, no matter how much length of rope actually remained. So if you re-light the remaining rope from the right side then it would take exactly 12 minutes to burn through the rest. Lighting both ends at the beginning just does this in parallel, with both flames eating through their 12 minutes of rope at the same time before colliding and burning out.

I would

 First light the 2 ends of the 50 minutes rope.
 When that rope is entirely burned 25 minutes (50/2) will have passed. I then light both ends and any midpoint of the other rope.
 If the flame from the midpoint reaches the flame from both ends at the same time, an additional 6 minutes (24/4) will have passed, totaling 25+6=31 minutes. Otherwise:
 When the flame from the midpoint reaches the flame from one end, light another midpoint on the part of the rope that is not yet burnt. Repeat this process until the midpoint flame reaches both ends at the same time.

This works because

 Two end flames and one midpoint flame always burn 4 "equal-time sections" of the rope. Call this time $x$. When a midpoint flame reaches an endpoint flame, there is $24-4x$ left of burnable rope. When this process is repeated, 4 smaller equal-time sections $y$ are burned, leaving $24-4x-4y$ of burnable rope after time $x+y$. This process is repeated until $24-\sum_i 4 x_i=0$ and takes time $\sum_i x_i$, which equals $6$ minutes by solving the equation.
 Of course, one may have to be infinitely quick about lighting a new midpoint if the midpoint flame does not reach both end flames simultaneously for any of the first few lightings.


+1 What a cool solution!

Indeed I like that, too. I have an Idea for a party gag: First I'll present the puzzle in its unaltered form. Then someone will come up with the easier and correct solution. Then scratching my head I'll notice: "Err, sorry, I explained it wrongly, You're not allowed to light the smaller rope until the longer one is all burned up." - That for sure will baffel the audience ;).

Thanks guys! @LordBo either that or the reverse order also works :) may no longer be a beginning puzzle

@QuantumMechanic Ahh, thanks, didn't see obvious here!

@LordBo or simply "both ropes cannot be burning at the same time"

Here's how I would do it:

 I would fold the 24" rope twice, making the rope four "strands" thick.


 I would fold the 50" rope once, making the rope two "strands" thick.


 Holding both folded ropes vertically, I would light the bottoms of them.


 Since the 24" rope must burn an average of 6 minutes per strand (some burn faster, some slower, but they must average 6 minutes if the entire rope burns in 24 mins), and the 50" rope must burn an average of 25 minutes per strand (again, one may burn faster and the other slower, but the average will be 25 mins if the entire rope burns in 50 mins), after both ropes are completely burned, 31 minutes will have passed.

Edit: Eh never mind... this wouldn't work since the limit is the longest burning rope.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

How can you measure 6 minutes with the 4 strands of the 24-minute rope if their burn times are 1, 1, 1 and 21 minutes?

I agree with @Will.Octagon.Gibson and the edit that this solution doesn't work as is, but if you continue from the end of your solution you get to my solution! So all is not lost
